# Position of jqueryUI tooltip using backbone

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, backbone.js

The position of my JqueryUI tooltip is always:
 top: -27911px; left: -27103px;

I notice that in my code it always gets inserted inside the  tag, where as on the JqueryUi website demo, it's always inserted in the markup near the actual item it's being attached to.

I suspect this might be because we are using backbone and our html file is mostly a skeleton until Backbone inserts the views etc.

You can see it by hovering over "Rating":
[image]

[on this page](http://dev2.whygo.eu/search.htm)

My backbone view:

```
events: {
      "hover #mytooltip" : "hoverRecommended",

},

hoverRecommended: function() {

        $( "#mytooltip" ).tooltip({

                });

    },
```

Comment: There is an error on the page you provided.  Could you recreate the problem using [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 4):

Why are you binding the `tooltip` multiple times to the element in question.

One thing I can think of is you have a missing `closing tag` .

Also you need to tie the tooltip in the render method , so that HTML is in place before assigning the tooltip.

```
assignToolTip: function () {

    $("#mytooltip").tooltip({

    });
},
render: {
    // Rendering the view

    // Then instantiate the tooltip

    this.assignTooltip();
}
```